Convergent sequences in a $T_2$ $G_{\delta}$ space; and the $K$-topology
Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $A \subseteq X$. $A$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set in $X$ if it is a countable intersection of open sets of $X$.
A finite union of $G_{\delta}$ sets is a $G_{\delta}$ set. But, a countable union of $G_{\delta}$ sets isn't necessarily a $G_{\delta}$ set. In my previous question, @Ulli showed me a good example of such ($\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology).
Before making that question, I was wondering if the $K$-topology is a $G_{\delta}$ space or not. And, after reading Ulli's answer, I got more interested in knowing the answer.
But first, I needed to answer the following question:
Let $X$ be a $T_2$ $G_{\delta}$ space. And, let $A = \{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$ converging to $p \in X$. Is $A \cup \{p\}$ a $G_{\delta}$ set? And, is $A \setminus \{p\}$ a $G_{\delta}$ set?

Let $X$ be a $T_2$ $G_{\delta}$ space. And, let $A = \{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$ converging to $p \in X$.
Each compact set in $X$ is closed, and, therefore, is also a $G_{\delta}$ set. So, $A \cup \{p\}$, which is compact, is a $G_{\delta}$ set; and there exists a countable collection of open sets of $X$, let's denote as $\mathcal{B}$, such that $A \cup \{p\} = \bigcap\mathcal{B}$.
Now, as $X$ is $T_1$, then $X \setminus \{p\}$ is open. Taking $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{B} \cup \{X \setminus \{p\}\}$, we have that $A = \bigcap\mathcal{A}$. So, $A$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set.
Let $Y$ be the $K$-topology ($K = \{\frac{1}{n+1} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, and open sets in $Y$ are of the form $U \cup (V \setminus K)$, where $U$ and $V$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology).
As $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology is a $T_2$ $G_{\delta}$ space, then $K$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology (as it is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology). And, as $Y$ is finer than $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, then $K$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set in $Y$.
Let $C$ be a closed set in $Y$. Then, there exists $U$ and $V$ open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology such that $C = \mathbb{R} \setminus (U \cup (V \setminus K))$.
We have that $C = \mathbb{R} \setminus (U \cup (V \setminus K)) = (\mathbb{R} \setminus U) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus (V \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus K)))) = (\mathbb{R} \setminus U) \cap ((\mathbb{R} \setminus V) \cup K)$. Therefore, $C$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set in $Y$.
We conclude that $Y$ is a $G_{\delta}$ space.
